# What does mean Python inputs incompatible with input_signature

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am getting the issue

```
ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
```

When I do :

```
image_np = np.asarray(np.array(Image.open(image_path)))
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

the issue happen precisely on this line :

```
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

What am I doing wrong ? What does this error mean ?

**Console Log**

```
ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
  inputs: (
    tf.Tensor(
[[[[255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]]

  [[254 254 254 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]]

  [[254 254 254 255]
   [254 254 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [255 255 255 255]]

  ...

  [[ 37  37  37 255]
   [ 37  37  37 255]
   [ 39  39  39 255]
   ...
   [ 32  32  32 255]
   [ 33  33  33 255]
   [ 31  31  31 255]]

  [[ 37  37  37 255]
   [ 38  38  38 255]
   [ 36  36  36 255]
   ...
   [ 33  33  33 255]
   [ 31  31  31 255]
   [ 32  32  32 255]]

  [[ 38  38  38 255]
   [ 37  37  37 255]
   [ 38  38  38 255]
   ...
   [ 32  32  32 255]
   [ 31  31  31 255]
   [ 32  32  32 255]]]], shape=(1, 1080, 1915, 4), dtype=uint8))
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name='input_tensor'))
```

Comment: the last dimensions differ (3 for model vs 4 for input)

Comment: @Andrey so how would I fix it ? What is `last dimensions` meaning .. Sorry I am new to python

Comment: based on your shape - I would suggest that you are trying to feed 4-channel image to the NN created for 3-channel. If so - you probably have to remove one channel. Or find the model with 4 channels

Comment: @Andrey how would you delete a channel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to feed 4-channel image to the NN with 3-channel input. Remove the last channel:

```
image_np = np.asarray(np.array(Image.open(image_path)))
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
input_tensor = input_tensor[:, :, :, :3] # <= add this line
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove alpha channel (4 to 3)

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(PATH_OF_IMAGE)
im = im.convert("RGB")

im.save(PATH_OF_IMAGE)
```